# Markdown Laravel printing html code

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel Markdown but still printing HTML code.

my model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use GrahamCampbell\Markdown\Facades\Markdown;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;


class Post extends Model
{

    public function getContentHtmlAttribute($value)
{

     return Markdown::convertToHtml(e($this->content));

}
}
```

my blade page

```
{!! $post->content_html !!}
```

printing

```
<h2 style="font-family: DauphinPlain; line-height: 24px; 
color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 24px; 
padding: 0px;">What is Lorem Ipsum?
```

Thank you

Comment: whata about {{ $post->content_html }} this .becasue in model you are alreaddy converting into html.that may be the reason

Comment: results are the same :(

Comment: let me install it and check once

Comment: even i tried same result no luck.

Comment: {!! html_entity_decode($post->content_html) !!}    try this and i dont say its good one but still working

Comment: the html_entity_decode works fine but that was the markdown job to do. and failed. but thanks iCoders i will use that.!!

Comment: ya i also knew but no luck i tried many methods .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{!! html_entity_decode($post->content_html) !!}
```

try this and i dont say its good one but still working –